# Eclipse CDT C++ semantic errors wxWidgets

Tags: c++, gcc, wxwidgets, eclipse-cdt

I am using **wxWidgets** to build a GUI application using Eclipse CDT (GNU C++) under Fedora Linux. The program compiles and runs fine, but in the Eclipse "problems" tab, there are so many "semantic errors" and "code analysis warnings".

I am wondering what are those errors and warnings, and how can I make it go away? My understanding is that it may have something to do with the compiler. I compile the same program under Visual C++ Express in Windows, and I don't see any of those "errors" or "warnings".

I create a wxWidgets objects, e.g., wxTextCtrl, and hit Ctrl + Space, but I don't see any member variables or methods there. Does it have anything to do with those "semantic errors" and "warnings"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDT does not know about your project's header search paths in your makefile unless you tell it about them.
Go to the `Project properties > C/C++ general > Paths and Symbols` and add any header search paths used by your project there.

[image]

You probably have those set up in Visual C++ already so you can look there to see which paths you need to add.